# finding the function of the intersection of two areas g1 and g2

Tags: graphics3d

How may I get the function of the intersection of the two areas as displayed in figures g1 and g2.

the code of g1 is

```
g1 = Plot3D[(0.5` ((0.25` + k \[Theta])/(1 + 0.25` k \[Theta]))^0.5`)/   k^0.5` + (0.5` k^0.5` (\[Theta]/(1 + 0.25` k \[Theta]) - (0.25` \[Theta] (0.25` + k \[Theta]))/(1 + 0.25` k \[Theta])^2))/((0.25` + k \[Theta])/(1 + 0.25` k \[Theta]))^0.5`, {k, 1, 2}, {\[Theta], 0.5, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"k", "\[Theta]", "Abl"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}]
```

the code of g2 is

```
g2 = Plot3D[1, {k, 1, 2}, {\[Theta], 0.5, 10},   AxesLabel -> {"k", "\[Theta]", "Abl"}]
```

Then the code

```
Show[g1,g2]
```

[image]

gives a graphical representation within a 3D-plot 
I would be happy to learn. thx
Ina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Solve for this:

```
sol = Solve[(0.5` ((0.25` + k \[Theta])/(1 + 0.25` k \[Theta]))^0.5`)/
    k^0.5` + (0.5` k^0.5` (\[Theta]/(1 + 
           0.25` k \[Theta]) - (0.25` \[Theta] (0.25` + 
             k \[Theta]))/(1 + 0.25` k \[Theta])^2))/((0.25` + 
         k \[Theta])/(1 + 0.25` k \[Theta]))^0.5` == 1, k]
```

To plot:

```
Plot[k /. 
  sol, {\[Theta], 0.5, 10}]
```

[image]